# HtmlHelper extension method in grid control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

I need some help creating this extension method.

My view inherits from

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/NoSideMenu.Master"
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<MyProject.Models.Customer>>" %>
```

And I have a grid control defined by

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("customer-history-grid").Footer(false).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.IsValidCustomer).Title(Html.Resource("ValidCustomerTableHeader"));
    }
    ).Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(25))
    .Footer(true)
    .Render(); 
    %>
```

Here I don't want to display the boolean value. Instead I want to display `Y` or `N`. For example if `o.IsValidCustomer` is true then `Y` else `N`.

I tried writing the below extension method

```
public static string ConvertToString<T, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression)
    {
        ......
    }
```

But my extension method picks up the `List<MyProject.Models.Customer>` type and not the `Customer` object. So I cannot select the method `o.IsValidCustomer` in the lambda expression for example

in View...

```
columns.Bound(o => o.IsValidCustomer).Format(Html.ConvertToString(o => o.IsValidCustomer)).Title(Html.Resource("ValidCustomerTableHeader"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to edit your domain model?

E.g. add this

```
public string IsValidCustomerString
{
    get { return IsValidCustomer ? "Y" : "N"; }
}
```

Then just bind that as a column?

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Yeah I like that. and your solution should work. However I did it in another way. Telerik provide a template helper so we can call the Html helper method as below

columns.Template(o =>
     {
      %>
       <%= Html.ConvertBooleanToYOrN(o.MultipleCurrencyFlag)%>
      <%
   }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "flag" }).Title(Html.Resource("MultipleCurrencyTableHeader"));


Thanks alot and appreciate your suggession.